# Minecraft doesn't launch with the Ultrasurf proxy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10, networking

I often go to the library to play Minecraft. Since there are a lot of people playing there, enough people put in the wrong credentials such that the library IP is often temporarily banned from the Mojang authentication servers.

VPNs don't work, as they need to install a network driver, which requires administrator privileges. Because of this, I've looked into using proxies like Ultrasurf, since they're the only other way around changing your IP AFAIK, and it seems that, although the traffic from the Minecraft launcher is sent through the proxy, any data sent from the Minecraft game ITSELF is not through the proxy.

I tested this by making my own server, and it always seemed to log the same library IP no matter what I tried. Yes, I tried putting flags like `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPORT -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyURL -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxyPORT`, but they always seem to do nothing.

This can be a problem, since whenever the library IP is temp banned, I can use a proxy to sign in with the launcher, but when it actually launches, it always presents to me an invalid session. Similarly, mods like In-Game Account Switcher always state that the username or password is incorrect.

Also, I tried using MultiMC and manually specifying a proxy in the settings. For example, using Ultrasurf, I would put 127.0.0.1:9666. For some reason, it STILL will not use that proxy, and I have tried setting it as both a SOCKS proxy and an HTTP proxy.

Comment: Is it even allowed to play Minecraft on library PCs?

Comment: Well, yes actually. A lot of people do, which is the problem. That's why the IP gets banned from the auth servers.

Comment: After doing some more research, I've heard that there's a known bug where Minecraft ignores proxies. It says that I need to SSH tunnel or something to get into multiplayer servers via proxy. How can I apply this to logging in? I know that the launcher will sign you in through the proxy... So if I open Minecraft, then SSH tunnel to Hypixel or something through the proxy, will it still give me an invalid session? If not, then how might I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something called Proxifier to force redirect all traffic through Ultrasurf, which just happens to be an HTTPS proxy `127.0.0.1:9666`. It also doesn't require admin if you use the portable version.